# com.android.volley.ClientError

Tags: android, volley, error404

tengo este problema:

usando ***volley*** para conectar con un web service ASP.Net de esta manera, me salta al onErrorResponse con el mensaje **"com.android.volley.ClientError"**. **En local sí que me funciona**

```
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    Map<String, String > params = new HashMap();
    params.put("userName", userTextView.getText().toString());
    params.put("userPass", passTextView.getText().toString());

    JSONObject parametros = new JSONObject(params);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = null;

    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, WebserviceConnection.getAbsoluteUrl("usuarios/"), parametros, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            UsuarioObject usuario = new UsuarioObject(response);

            checkUser(usuario);
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.d("Login", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Lo primero a revisar es si  la URL: `WebserviceConnection.getAbsoluteUrl("usuarios/")` **es correcta y funcional**. Luego, creo que debes quitarle los parámetros de `jsonObjectRequest` y pasarlos desde el método `getParams`. Algo así: `@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError { Map<String, String > params = new HashMap();
    params.put("userName", userTextView.getText().toString());
    params.put("userPass", passTextView.getText().toString()); return params; }`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya logré solucionarlo. El problema estaba en la URL.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Lo he escrito en respuesta por si puede servir a alguien más. Saludos.

Comment: Para servicios web intenta utilizar `HttpURLConnection`; recuerda que debes manejar asynctask ya que lo debes correr en un hilo que no sea el principal.

Comment: Eso era aaaaantes. Ya `Volley` superó todas esas complicaciones. Cuando empecé con Android me parecía tan complicado el uso que mencionas... Menos mal que investigando di con `Volley` y ya no lo cambio por nada.

Answer (score 2):

Dado que dices que en local te funciona, entonces revisa tu URL: **`WebserviceConnection.getAbsoluteUrl("usuarios/")`**, es muy probable que la misma no sea correcta o que no sea funcional en tu entorno, debido a que no apunta a un recurso válido o a que se está creando mal.